# Is it legally allowed to install lightning rods in rainy or cloudy weather?

Tags: protection, solar-energy, surge-protection, standard, lightning

I had a look at some standards (such as [IEC 62305 & IEC 62561 *Standards for Lightning Protection*](https://axis-india.com/iec-62305-iec-62561-international-standards-for-lightning-protection/)) on how lightning rods should be constructed, and also searched the internet.  I found no real answers to this question, including Google and Stackexchange. There are of course some "suggestions", but none of them say this as a "rule".

I live in Germany, and in Germany, the responsible body for this work is "VDE Verband der Elektrotechnik Elektronik Informationstechnik e.V. Ausschuss für Blitzschutz und Blitzforschung (ABB.)" A [useful official resource](https://www.vde.com/resource/blob/936850/b2b4d67bf5ff269180a7469ce620dcbb/vde-merkblatt-blitzschutz-veranstaltungen-download-data.pdf) is available on their [website](https://www.vde.com/de/blitzschutz/ueber-uns/abb).

Of course, in weather like this, I also think it's not a good idea, and as an electrical engineer, I want to protect my colleagues on my team. I can't do anything at the moment other than recommending to the top managers of my company that such installations be done during sunny weather.

Is there a rule or prohibition on when lightning rods may be installed?

Comment: Depends on where you are (laws vary around the world you know) but the question is a bit like "is there a law against playing with knives", the answer is only the law of common sense.

Comment: Welcome! Depends on local laws. Where I live, any electrical work must start with a risk assessment and thunderstorms or risk thereof is part of it, at which point you will be restricted to what you're allowed to do.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answers. I just edited my question to add my location. According to the occupational safety rules here, we also need to make this risk assessment. But since I am not an occupational safety expert, I have no idea about it. This is a very good idea and I will discuss it with our occupational safety specialist.

Comment: You might check into local building codes. There are likely rules that mandate lighting rods on buildings of certain heights.  The building codes might specify the actual (mechanical and electrical) requirements for such devices.

Comment: I think there is a straightforward process: write a risk assessment or get one written for the work. This will have to include something about the weather. In the UK I would include “All work is to be halted if there is any risk of lighting strike”. There would clearly be other points about the weather including rain, wind, temperature etc.

Comment: Is it much different to drilling a hole in the ground to reach water or oil? Would that process stop in cloudy weather. Note that I have no idea what the actual process is in detail.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's an Occupational Health & Safety question, not an engineering question.

Comment: Professional golf tournaments use a device that looks for lightning strikes in the area. Play is suspended if it detects any. It is more sensitive than a human's eyes. If you work in high, unprotected areas, I recommend you get one of these devices. Then, you won't be relying on biased human opinion. Sorry, I don't know where to get one, only that they exist.

Comment: In the US, this may fall under OSHA.

Comment: @Mattman944 A field mill?

Answer (score 0):

VDE regulations are about the safety of installations and tools.  Labor safety regulations are a different kettle.